# Summary Fields - Cannot recreate sum fields after upgrading from 4.01.0 to 4.0.2

Tags: summaryfields

Drupal 5.10.0, Civi 5.10.0, Sum fields 4.0.2. After upgrading to 4.0.2 (because our Civi menu bar disappeared after previous upgrade) I noted our contact records Summary Fields tab was not populating with any values (blank box).
I then went to Administer/Custom data and fields/Summary Fields and noted that none of the sum fields boxes were checked. I checked all of the contribution boxes and tried to save them. Unfortunately I receive this error message - "Failed to get the custom group parameters. Can't add fields."
The current status of this extension indicates that the "Setting changes failed to apply" and it added the date/time stamp of the failure.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may want to open an Issue on the extensions' github page: https://github.com/progressivetech/net.ourpowerbase.sumfields/issues